# determine ir protocol without ir controller

Tags: microcontroller, infrared

I have the following issue:
I bought an ir controller for my Blaupunkt radio which has an built in ir reciever.The problem is that the controller does not works togather with the radio.
Its seem they use different protocols.I know how to decode an ir controller signals with arduino but don't know how to get it without controller.
The radio has an ST6285  MCU and reads the ir input on the FB port.
But further i have no idea how can i get to know the used infra protocol.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Unless someone has published this somewhere, you need to take the model number and search for a replacement remote.

Comment: Blaupunkt. European make. Start with a guess that it uses the Philips RC5 protocol. Find an RC5 handset (or generate RC5 from the Arduino) and see if a few common commands (address=amplifier, cmd=volume up) work.

Comment: I have an RC-12H controller but it does not work.Is that possible that Blaupunkt changed protocol over the time?

Comment: As @dwelch says, if this is unpublished, then you may be forced to obtain a replacement remote. If the remote is no longer produced (Blaupunkt is forcing you to buy a new radio), then I'd haughtily suggest finding one, hacking it, decyphering the protocol, and publishing the results for others to use.

Comment: I wouldnt assume they use the same protocol forever.  And within a protocol there can be waht 16 to 32 bits, so tens of thousands to billions of separate commands.  you could walk through all of them with a blaster, I guess leave that running for a while, if nothing happens either you dont have the right protocol or you dont have it sent out right.

Comment: is this something a universal remote might support?

Comment: Some models of android phones have infrared led. Softwares for them usually loaded with hundreds of controller scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Consider investigating if the [JP1 project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JP1_remote) has analyzed your particular radio's IR remote control communications / protocol.  If they have, consider obtaining one of the JP1 recommended remotes and reprogramming it with those codes.  Note, the JP1 effort is based on unsupported features of a certain brand of remote controls.